# What is this RS-485 communication protocol/

Tags: hardware, serial-communication

I am trying to reverse engineer a two wire RS-485 standard serial bus interface to talk to a [samsung heat pump](https://www.samsung.com/uk/business/climate/ac-dvm-amxxxfnbdeh/am320fnbdeheu/).

Here are some hex commands I was able to sniff. Every message starts with `0x32` and ends with `0x34`. Does someone recognise this protocol?

```
32 00 1A 80 FF 00 10 00 00 C0 11 ED 01 06 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B7 C8 34 
32 00 17 10 00 00 80 FF 00 C0 15 ED 01 06 0C 82 02 48 5A 16 04 23 13 8C 34 
32 00 11 80 FF 00 10 00 00 C0 11 EE 01 86 01 00 0D 2E 34 
32 00 11 80 FF 00 10 00 00 C0 11 EF 01 86 0A 00 7B 85 34
```

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE! May be worth having a look at [these search results](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=serial%20protocol) (sorted by newest first).

Comment: what's on the other side of the wire? did you try to extract/RE its firmware/software?

Answer (score 0):

```
 By0 - 32 start frame  
 By1 - 00 source address  
 By2 - 1A, 17 11 - destination address  
 By3 - 80,10 -> command  
 By4 ... ByN-2 data  
 ByN-1 ... CRC XOR of By1 to ByN-2  
 ByN - 34 End of Frame
```